# jQuery and iframe designMode

Tags: jquery, iframe

Sorry to ask this question but i'm sure some other web developers might find the solution to this question helpful as well.

While referenecing this in jQuery

```
$(function(){
    // $("#iframe").designMode = 'on';
    // $("#iframe").attr("designMode", "on");
});
```

the code does not work. I know i can easily reference the code by using javascript

```
iframe.document.designMode = 'on';
```

But i would prefer to be able to use JQuery.

Comment: You are using `#iframe`, is it really the ID of that iframe?

Comment: yes <iframe id='iframe'></iframe>

Comment: i just found something about a plugin, is the plugin a must? if so i wont use this.http://www.jquery-plugins.info/view.php?id=12477

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `$('#iframe')[0].document.designMode = 'on';`

Or

`$('#iframe').contents().prop('designMode','on')`

Comment: ive tried the first one before, the second one works :3 ur a genius :3

Answer (score -1):

try `$('iframe#iframe').attr('designMode', 'on');`

Comment: Why would that do anything different from `$('#iframe').attr('designMode', 'on');`

Comment: well, it's worth the try

Comment: All that will do is return the same elements but take longer to do so. `$('iframe#iframe')` just gets the set of `<iframe>` tags with id iframe and since id selectors are optimized in jQuery not including the element type runs faster.

Comment: the designMode do not apply to the iframe but to its content